# Javascript - Factorial from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a simple script that calculates the factorials. So for example if you enter "2!+5!+4" you will get "2+120+4". I don't know how you would do it.

```
function factorial(num) {
      if (num < 0) 
          return -1;
      else if (num == 0) 
        return 1;
      else {
        return (num * factorial(num - 1));
      }
  }

var calcvalue = "2!+5!+4";
var facregex = /(\d)+\!/gi;
var facmatch = calcvalue.match(/(\d)+\!/gi);
var faclength = calcvalue.match(/(\d)+\!/gi).length;
console.log(faclength);

for (var i = 0; i < faclength; i++) {
var calcvalue = calcvalue.replace(facmatch[i], toString(factorial(Number(facmatch[i]))));
} 

console.log("Final: "+calcvalue);
```

Comment: Is it always + in between numbers?

Comment: No. There is not.

Comment: `"2!+5!-4"` so this is also possible?

Comment: Yes it would output "2+120-4".

Comment: You’re doing string replace which will replace the first instance of the digit, which might not be the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace any occurences of `\d+` followed by `!` with the result of the factorial of the `\d+` part (which should be grouped):

```
var result = mathString.replace(/(\d+)!/g, function(match, number) {
    return factorial(+number);
});
```

Shorter using an arrow function:

```
var result = mathString.replace(/(\d+)!/g, (m, n) => factorial(+n));
```

**Example:**

```js
function factorial(num) {
  if (num <= 1) 
    return 1;

  return num * factorial(num - 1);
}

var mathString = "2!+5!+4";
var result = mathString.replace(/(\d+)!/g, (m, n) => factorial(+n));
console.log(result);
```

**Note:** Don't care whether the factorial bit is preceded by a `-` or `+` as it will stay there, hence the numbers retrieved by the regex will always be `>= 0`, so the `factorial` function could be simplified (see the snippett code).

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `+` inside the capture group, not after it.

```
var facregex = /(\d+)!/g;
```

Both of them match all the digits, but your version only captures the first digit, instead of all the digits.

You don't need a `for` loop, because you can give a function to the `replace()` function. It receives the match and all the capture groups as parameters, and returns the replacement.

```js
var origValue = "2!+10!+4";
var facregex = /(\d+)!/g;

var calcValue = origValue.replace(facregex, function(match, group1) {
    return factorial(Number(group1));
});

console.log(calcValue);

function factorial(num) {
  if (num < 0)
    return -1;
  else if (num == 0)
    return 1;
  else {
    return (num * factorial(num - 1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Replace the `!(Sign)` before parsing `facmatch[i]` to `Number`.

**2.** Use `eval` to get the **final calculation** from **string result**.

```js
function factorial(num) {
      if (num < 0) 
          return -1;
      else if (num == 0) 
        return 1;
      else {
        return (num * factorial(num - 1));
      }
  }

var calcvalue = "2!+5!+4";
var facregex = /(\d)+\!/gi;
var facmatch = calcvalue.match(/(\d)+\!/gi);
var faclength = calcvalue.match(/(\d)+\!/gi).length;
//console.log(faclength,facmatch);
for (var i = 0; i < faclength; i++) {
var fact=factorial(Number(facmatch[i].replace("!","")));
//console.log("Final: "+fact);
calcvalue= calcvalue.replace(facmatch[i], fact);

} 
console.log("Final: "+eval(calcvalue));
```